# How to ignore string empty values when mapping a column to a DateTime property in SQLlite?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, datetime

I use Entity Framework to read a SQLite database from a C# console app.

Here is the problem : I have many columns that contains empty string (eg : '') and are mapped to a DateTime property in C#.

When I try to read those records here is the error I got :

> Innermost exception    System.FormatException : String '' was
>   not recognized as a valid DateTime.    at
>   System.DateTimeParse.Parse(ReadOnlySpan`1 s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi,
>   DateTimeStyles styles)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteValueReader.GetDateTime(Int32 ordinal)

Mapping the column to a nullable DateTime does not solve the problem.

Obvious solution is to clean up ALL those empty strings and replace them by NULL values. This is not trivial in my case and I cannot guarantee there won't be any other string empty values in the future.

Surprisingly, if a column mapped to an integer contains a empty string value, it works (value is mapped to '0').

Is there a way to ignore those empty string values when mapping to a DateTime ? (eg : it will return a null date or DateTime.MinValue). Note : I use ISO 8601 format not ticks.

EDIT : 
Here is my code

```
public class FooContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder) {     
           builder.UseSqlite("Data Source=Database.db");
    }

    public DbSet<Bar> Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SomeDate { get; set; }
}

using(FooContext context = new FooContext())
{                
    var bar = context.Find<Bar>(id); //throw exception
}
```

Comment: Could you please the code you use to read the records you mentioned ? Thanks

Comment: I have edited question

Comment: Which version of EF you are using?

Comment: @Aldert I'm using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have to handle this on `OnModelCreating` method of your context class. Actually you have to override this method. In this method we create a converter that would be used for the conversion of the value we read from the database for the property `SomeDate`:

```
public class FooContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder) {     
           builder.UseSqlite("Data Source=Database.db");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        DateTime parsedDateTime;
        var converter = new ValueConverter<string, DateTime?>(
            v => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(v)
                ? null
                : DateTime.TryParse(v, out parsedDateTime)
                    ? parsedDateTime
                    : (DateTime?) null,
            v => v != null
                ? v.ToString()
                : string.Empty);

        modelBuilder
           .Entity<Bar>()
           .Property(b=>b.SomeDate)
           .HasConversion(converter);
    }    

    public DbSet<Bar> Bar { get; set; }
}
```

You could read more regarding value conversion [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions).

Comment: Is there a way to setup a converter called for all date time fields ? (so I don't have to hardcode HasConversion() calls for all possible fields of all tables). I know I could do that by reflection, but maybe there is a better way.

Comment: @tigrou I am not aware of such a thing. Also I searched a bit and I didn't find anything. However, IMHO it is better to state explicitly using the API that EFCore provides you that than use reflection.